# Seaborn pairplot not working fine using anaconda and pycharm. getting Degrees of freedom warning

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda, seaborn

I am very new to using python data science libraries. I am using PyCharm as IDE and Anaconda Python 3.7 Interpreter.

I have Anaconda3 and I'm using Jupyter Notebook. I have a csv file named smartphones.csv which has the details in the picture below and I imported all necessary libraries.

[image: Data]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
```

And I am using this code to get DataFrame from csv

```
smartphone = pd.read_csv("F://Data//smartphones.csv")
```

and it works fine and `print(smartphone)` print the data as intended.

After that I tried to use seaborn pairplot with this codes:

```
sb.pairplot(smartphone, hue='Name', palette='hls')
plt.show()
```

It works but some of the plots are not as they should be and I get this warnings:

```
C:\Users\All Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:140: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  keepdims=keepdims)
C:\Users\All Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:132: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
```

And the result is
[image]

But it should be something like this:[image]

I also tested this with Jupyter and the result was the same and I got the same plot and warnings. What should I do to fix this warnings and get the correct plot?

P.S:
If you want to test the problem with my data, you could use this code:

```
smartphone_arr = [['Galaxy S8', 'Android' ,64, 4, 149.0 ,'Samsung' ,5.8],
 ['Lumia 950' ,'windows ' ,32 ,3 ,150.0 ,'Microsoft' ,5.2],
 ['Xpreia L1' ,'Android' ,16 ,2, 180.0 ,'Sony' ,5.5],
 ['iphone 7 ' ,'ios' ,128, 2 ,138.0 ,'Apple' ,4.7],
 ['U Ultra' ,'Android' ,64 ,4 ,170.0 ,'HTC', 5.7],
 ['Galaxy S5', 'Android' ,16, 2 ,145.0 ,'Samsung' ,5.1],
 ['iphone 5s' ,'ios', 32, 1 ,112.0 ,'Apple', 4.0],
 ['Moto G5', 'Android' ,16, 3, 144.5 ,'Motorola', 5.0],
 ['Pixel ' ,'Android', 128 ,4 ,143.0, 'Google' ,5.0]]

smartphone = pd.DataFrame(smartphone_arr,index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] , columns=["Name" , "OS" , "Capacity" , "RAM" , "Weight" , "Company" , "Inch"])
```

P.S.2: I used diag-kind = 'hist'. The Warnings disappeared; but the plot is still not fine.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems like an error would occur if you don't specify the `diag_kind` argument; here is the [issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1627) you could read on.

```py
# diag_kind : {'auto', 'hist', 'kde'}
sb.pairplot(smartphone, hue='Name', palette='hls', diag_kind='hist')
```

---

EDIT:

Both `diag_kind='kde'` and `diag_kind='auto'` work if you don't specify `hue` argument (more on this [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1502)):

```py
sb.pairplot(smartphone, diag_kind='auto')
```

[image]

Comment: I used diag-kind = 'hist'. The Warnings disappeared; but the plot is still not fine. I uploaded a picture above. Also removing hue, make plot monochrome.

Can you say what should I use to get the plot like the one I uploaded? It is from a video tutorial and the lecturer just get the correct colored result without diag-kind.

Comment: @amirna I don't know mate, I'm sorry. That's an interesting issue here